# useSelector returns undefined on console.log

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

the code

```
const Question = () => {

    const idd = useSelector(state => state.idd)
    const questions = useSelector(state => state.questions)
    console.log(questions)

    console.log(idd)
    return(
     <>
     </>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ authedUser, questions, users }, { id }) => {
    const idd = id
    console.log(idd)

    return {
        authedUser,
        questions,
        users,
        idd
    }
}
```

the result of console.log(questions) print questions

---

the result of console.log(idd) is `udefined` can you help me please?

Comment: Didn't you mean to call ``state.id`` from your ``useSelector`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just get it from props directly by adding props to Component=(props)
and console.log(props.id)

Comment: Your answer here might get you what you want but isn't an answer as to why it returned ``undefined`` from your selector.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like something named "idd" was ever part of your Redux store? In that case, yes, it is completely normal to get `undefined` here - `useSelector` only gives you access to your Redux store.

`useSelector` has nothing to do with `mapStateToProps` (that just maps state to props, as the name implies) and you should not use `useSelector` and `connect/mapStateToProps` together and prefer `useSelector` whenever possible.